# ASP.NET MVC2 Deploying to a server

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, directory, remote-server

Hey I created a default MVC2 project just to see if i could get it to run on my site hosted by MochaHost. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to display the page instead it just displays the directory.

Has anybody had this problem before? Or know of a tutorial that may help?

Answer (score 0):

Did you confirm with MochaHost if they are running on IIS6? I suggest open a ticket with them and understand what they have in the environment.

Here is a tutorial for deploying MVC with IIS6: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/07/04/options-for-deploying-aspnet-mvc-to-iis-6/

You can also try disabling the directory browsing so that you know if there is a real problem.

Comment: They are running iis7 and I enabled directory browsing because it would just throw an error saying can't view directory. Thanks for the link though ill check it out when I get onto a computer.